# Improvements in gzip decompression java

Tags: java, oracle, gzip

**Scenario :**
I have almost close to 15 million records in oracle database, each of that record has a column which is compressed. The task is to export the same table but with the column value decompressed. My solution steps are given below,

```
- Read a chunk of data using jdbcTemplate (returns List)
 - For each of the record above decompress the column value and form an updated list
 - Use the above list to insert into another table (This is being executed by another thread).
```

Hence for a batch of 48842 records here are the analysis,

```
- Reading takes around 9 seconds
 - Writing takes around 47 seconds    
 - Compression takes around 135 seconds
```

With the above analysis for processing 15 million records, the process would take around 16 - 17 hours. Is there a way to improve it in anyway?
I am looking a vast area of improvement in decompression technique. Even small amount of improvement in the decompression technique would be a very huge difference in my case. Any help would be really appreciated.

Below is the decompressing method that I am using,

```
public String decompressMessage(String message)
    throws Exception
    {
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayIPStream = null;
        GZIPInputStream gZipIPStream = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String decompressedMessage = "";
        String line="";
        byte[] compressByteArray = null;
        try{
            if(message==null || "".equals(message))
            {
                logger.error("Decompress is not possible as the string is empty");
                return "";
            }
            compressByteArray = Base64.decode(message);
            byteArrayIPStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressByteArray);
            gZipIPStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayIPStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gZipIPStream, "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                
                decompressedMessage = decompressedMessage + line;               
              }
            return decompressedMessage;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Exception while decompressing the message with details {}",e);
            return "";
        }
        finally{
            line = null;
            compressByteArray = null;
            if(byteArrayIPStream!=null)
                byteArrayIPStream.close();
            if(gZipIPStream!=null)
                gZipIPStream.close();
            if(bufferedReader!=null)
                bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: just to start: use a StringBuffer for `decompressedMessage`

Comment: Awesome way to start with :) Thank you wero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly the biggest issue is concatenating a string in a loop. Strings are immutable which means you are imposing O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity to an essentially O(n) job.

Replace the string with a `StringWriter` and also remove `BufferedReader` from the input side. Use `Reader#read(char[])` followed by `StringWriter#write(char[])` to accumulate the data in the `StringWriter`, then in the end get the string with `StringWriter.toString()`.

Comment: I went with wero (Person who commented on the question) suggestion and used StringBuffer and it improved drastically. I would like to ask you, Is using StringWriter appropriate here? And Can you send me updated method with your approach? I am not able to use Reader like the way you told. (What is wrong in using StringBuffer and BufferedReader is the underline question here)!!!

Comment: The optimum way to transfer data is over a fixed-size buffer. `readLine` must needlessly scan the input char by char, looking for a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Let the Oracle database do it.  For example:

```
-- NOTE: This example would be simpler if compressed_data were a RAW type...
create table matt1 ( compressed_data VARCHAR2(4000) );

-- Put 100,000 rows of compressed data in there
insert into matt1 (compressed_data)
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_compress.lz_compress(src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_random.string('a',30) || 'UNCOMPRESSED_DATA' || lpad(rownum,10,'0') || dbms_random.string('a',30))))
from dual
connect by rownum <= 100000;

-- Create the uncompressed version of the table to export
create table matt1_uncompressed as
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_compress.lz_uncompress(src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(compressed_data))) uncompressed_data
from matt1
where rownum <= 100000;

--- execution time was 3.448 seconds
```

### Update for sample data posted by OP

It looks like the data in your example is base64 encoded.  Try this:

```
SELECT utl_compress.lz_uncompress(src =>     
utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(your_table.compressed_column)))
from your_table;
```

Comment: Your approach seems fine if I have control over compression technique. The problem is the data is already compressed using gzip technique and I am not doing it. Is there a gzip decompressing technique in oracle itself?

Comment: According to the Oracle Documentation, `UTL_COMPRESS` is compatible with gzip.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_compr.htm

Comment: @Matthew McPeak - it is more or less compatible, UTL_COMRESS does not store checksum at the end. And also till 11gR1 (including) there was a bug in this package, The compression ratio never got bellow 50%.

Comment: Regarding the checksum., this link might be useful for that: https://technology.amis.nl/2010/03/13/utl_compress-gzip-and-zlib/.   Without a sample of his compressed data, it's hard to be sure.  My point is that Oracle does have, what they claim, are gzip-compatible decompression routines, and using them seems much faster than what he's been able to achieve with Java so far.  Considering the source data is in Oracle and the destination data must be in Oracle, doing the decompression in Oracle should be tried.

Comment: Matthew, I see a disconnect here, one example of compressed text in my case would be 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAAAAA=' How would you decompress this directly from oracle? That is what the data is being stored in oracle. Basically my question is if a text is being compressed (gzip compression) will it be same if it is done from oracle using UTL_COMPRESS and the other using Java? Whatever observations I have, it contradicts to what you are saying.

Comment: @Kiran -- post a few values of the compressed column along with a DUMP(column_name) for each.

Comment: @Kiran -- it looks like your compressed text is encoded in base64.  So, you need to decode that back and then uncompress it.  (Your example decompresses to NULL, but it does work.)  I updated my answer with a `SELECT` that should work for your table.  Please give it a try.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I tried the query
SELECT utl_compress.lz_uncompress(src => utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(MyTable.Column)))
from MyTable;

It gave the output as 

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 39

I am using sql developer with oracle 10g.

Comment: Try it without the `src =>` part.  Just `SELECT utl_compress.lz_uncompress(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(MyTable.Column))) from MyTable`

Comment: This worked Matthew but unfortunately I have limited buffer size. This is giving error the moment I have large data. The error is,

ORA-24345: A Truncation or null fetch error occurred
24345. 00000 -  "A Truncation or null fetch error occurred"
*Cause:    A truncation or a null fetch error"
*Action:   Please ensure that the buffer size is long enough to
           store the returned data. But none the less its a very good approach.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  I believe the ORA-24345 can probably be overcome.  Is the encrypted data in your table being stored in a CLOB?